# Animate scrollTop laggy on Chrome only

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, frontend

Bootstrap 5.1.3 and jQuery 3.6.0

Animation not start immediately after click on Chrome, but works normally on other browser.

Sometimes the animation start after a while (maybe 500 ms) after click, sometimes it start with slow speed then as normal.

I tried this minimal code below and the problem still appears.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#scroll-top").click(function() {
    $("body,html").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-secondary" style="height:2500px;"></div>
  <p class="mb-0 text-center"><a href="javascript:;" id="scroll-top" class="text-dark text-decoration-none">Back to Top</a></p>
</body>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9j4hwn5q/)

I tried this code below (older version of Bootstrap 4.6.1), animation works normally.

So this problem may only appears on Bootstrap 5 and Chrome, I have no idea what caused it and how to fix it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#scroll-top").click(function() {
    $("body,html").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-secondary" style="height:2500px;"></div>
  <p class="mb-0 text-center"><a href="javascript:;" id="scroll-top" class="text-dark text-decoration-none">Back to Top</a></p>
</body>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4cz8we5/)

Comment: This seems to be a bug. It's working fine in Firefox but lag in Chrome and MS Edge. Maybe open new issue on [their GitHub](https://jsfiddle.net/o4cz8we5/)?

Comment: You have content (script elements) outside the head and body elements. This is invalid HTML. I've corrected it in the snippets, but be aware. Also, the second snippet has an error both here and at JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I submitted an issue on github and found the solution. [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/35536)

jQuery scroll script has conflict with scroll-behavior: smooth in _reboot.scss line 33. Just override it with css. [solution](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/35536#issuecomment-992327098)

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Tons of different topics on this issue, and this is definitely the fix. Thanks for posting it, Fire.

Comment: confirm. Best solution.